# How to integrate pancakeswap sdk to nestjs project?

Tags: nestjs, blockchain

I need to integrate Pancakeswap into my company project to get price and implement buy/sell transaction. I can see that Pancakeswap now only have Pancakeswap sdk v2. How can I connect that to nestjs to get the coin info and implement transaction? Thanks.